# Parse html file body using jsdom

Tags: node.js, protractor, jsdom

Firstly I am new to UI stuff so please keep this in mind before giving a solution.
 I have a url which I pass to jsdom in protractor spec file. It returns response which has to be parsed.
Jsdom logic:

```
   describe('angularjs homepage', function () {

        it('open nho website', function () {
         const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
         window = (new JSDOM(``, { runScripts: 'dangerously', url: 'https://example.com/getSeleniumGrid.jsp?locale=US&browser=Firefox&fabric=corp&teamName=xyzTeam' })).window;
//Used so many permutations n combinations on windows object
         const machinename=window.text();
         console.log("hi:"+machinename);

        });
    });
```

My html response

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>


    </head>
    <body>
        example.com

    </body>
</html>
```

I want what's inside the body. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The API `new JSDOM('<put html code at here>', options)` require you pass-in pre-know HTML code, if you want jsom to fetch the HTML code from a given url, you can't use this API, but use `JSDOM.fromURL(url, options)`

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function () {

    it('open nho website', function () {

        var jsdom = require("jsdom");

        var url = 'https://example.com/getSeleniumGrid.jsp?locale=US&browser=Firefox&fabric=corp&teamName=xyzTeam';

        // if your network access behind proxy, 
        // please create a resourceLoader, and
        // specify the resources in below options and pass the options
        // into JSDOM.fromURL(url, options)

        var resourceLoader = new jsdom.ResourceLoader({
            proxy: "<your proxy address>", 
            strictSSL: false,
        });

        var options = { 
            resources: resourceLoader,
        };

        jsdom.JSDOM.fromURL(url, options) 

        .then(function(dom){
            console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector('body').textContent.trim())
        });

    });
});
```